# Change of variables with a specific substitution

Tags: multivariable-calculus, jacobian, change-of-variable

> Let $\Omega = \left \{(x,y) : x^2-y^2 \leq 1, xy \leq 1, y \leq x, 0 \leq y \right \} \subset \mathbb{R}^2$. Find $\int_{\Omega}(x^2+y^2)dV$ using the substitution $v=x^2-y^2, u=xy$.

I'm pretty sure we can show that the substitution is a bijection (excluding $\partial \Omega) $ with $\Omega'= \left \{ (u,v) : 0 \leq u,v \leq 1 \right \}$.

And also $J^{-1}=det(\frac{\partial v,u}{\partial x,y}) = 2x^2+2y^2 \implies J = \frac{1}{2x^2+2y^2}$

But we need $J$ to be a function of $u,v$ and I don't see how we can get that, help appreciated.

Comment: your integral says $dV$, should it be $dA$ or $dx dy$? Also pls see your integrand, Jacobian will cancel out. Also in your region, $y \geq x$ or $x \geq y$? Pls check.

Comment: @MathLover Yes $x \geq y$, my bad.
I noticed that it cancels out but i got the wrong solution this way for some reason...

Comment: $dV$ is just notation, same as $dA$

Comment: @Math Lover I get that the answer is 1/2 this way but it doesn't make sense :<

Comment: Oh sorry maybe this answer is correct? For some reason I expected to get the area...

Comment: Yes the answer seems correct. You have an integrand so it will not give you area.